# Stack overflow when accessing translated ontology in python

Tags: python, ontology, owlready

I have a really simple piece of code but it already runs into an error. My piece of code
should just iterate over the class names in an ontology and print them out. This works for the first 20 or
so, but then this error occurs:

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow. 

Current thread 0x0000000106d2ae00 (most recent call first): 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/util.py", line 249 in __enter__ 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 543 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 540 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid 
  File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 558 in _load_by_storid 
  ... 
[1]    51983 abort      python owl_to_nodenames.py
```

My code using owlready2 is only those 4 lines:

```
from owlready2 import get_ontology 
onto = get_ontology("Ontologie.owl").load() 
for this in onto.classes(): 
    print(this)
```

Can you point me to the error? I originally tried it on a MacBook, but now I also tested it on a computer running Arch, same error.

Comment: The problem is likely in your ontology.  There might a cycle defined in  the ontology.   A is subclass of B, and B is subclass of A.   You might need to share the ontology so we can point the issue.

Comment: Sadly I can't share the ontology. But thank you anyways for answering this! I will take a look if there are any cycles in it.

Comment: That line (`File "/Users/PATH/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 538 in _get_by_storid`) is a recursion error (https://github.com/pwin/owlready2/blob/master/namespace.py#L538), so there is something refereeing to itself in your ontology.

Comment: Cycles are not uncommon in OWL and are not forbidden ... so in this case it would be a bug in `owlready2` from my point of view. Or a limitation but then it should be documented somewhere.

Comment: @UninformedUser Really? I reported this as a bug, keeping this question open just in case it isn't.

Comment: Not sure if is a bug but at least cycles in OWL shouldn't break an API - if it can't handle cycles a more meaningful exception would be better I think. I mean, you could try with a minimal ontology having a cycle if it still fails. Otherwise, as we don't know your ontology we can't judge. Clearly, you could load your ontology into Protege and see if it works, maybe also apply a reasoner.

Comment: Problem is, it was exported from Protege and there it worked. And I too think that there should be a better exception than an error message.